# How do I use an ATTiny board with right angled pins on a breadboard?

Tags: attiny, breadboard

I created a project on an Uno as a proof of concept and now have reduced the code and squeezed it onto an ATTiny.

Before I transfer it all to a PCB I want to get it going on a solderless breadboard to make sure everything is still working (I don't quite trust my soldering :P ) and also optimise the layout.

The issue is that an ATTiny has pins at right angles to each other,

[image]

so no matter which way it is turned, a row of pins will be *along* a strip of electrically connected holes on the breadboard.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use that breakout board. Use a DIP ATTiny, which will fit into a breadboard just fine.

Alternatively, use jumper wires to connect that board to your breadboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use an SOIC to DIP breakout board like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13655).
There are endless versions available online.

If you want to use you whole dev board on a breadboard use a Type A breakout board like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12700) to power it, and use jumpers to connect to the I/O pins.

[image]